# Wait for database result in GWT Async call

Tags: java, mysql, gwt

Is there any way I can wait for the database to return the result before the comparison is made?

```
private boolean checkAuthantication(String email, String password) {
    String encryptedPassword = encryptPassword(password);
    String dbPassword = Comav200.GetInstance().getPasswordFromDatabase(email);

    if (encryptedPassword.equals(dbPassword)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the problem?  Since it returns a value, `Comav200.GetInstance().getPasswordFromDatabase(email)' must be synchronous?

Comment: Well, the problem is that encryptedPassword is compared to dbPassword before dbPassword has a value. The checkAuthantication is trigger by a mouse click and the first time I click dbPassword is NULL.

Comment: You should look into why Comav200.GetInstance().getPasswordFromDatabase(email) is returning null for the first call.

Comment: Since I'm using GWT the call to the database is asynchronous and the comparison is made before it has returned a value

Comment: Can you post relevant parts of you Async and Service interfaces, and service impl, as well as the code that calls `checkAuthantication`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you use AsyncCallback?

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gwt/gwt_rpc_communication.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop or a timer of 2-3 seconds. But I think your code automatically waits untill the dbPassword is filled.